# framer-motion AnimatePresence layout issue

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm having an issue using the [framer-motion AnimatePresence component](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/).

While switching between slides, the slide's layout "shrinks" for a moment before extracting back to its desired dimensions. After some debugging, I'm pretty sure this is caused because `AnimatePresence` is rendering both slides at the same time for a tiny moment, however I didn't manage to get this fixed.

Here is a [sandbox demonstrating the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-monad-ochux?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [new beta `exitBeforeEnter` prop](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#animatepresenceprops.exitbeforeenter) did the trick:

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
  ...
</AnimatePresence>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a beta feature, you could just put a delay on the exit variant.

Also, might want to position the slide absolute.

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-ganguly-38mmc

Answer (score 1):

'exitBeforeEnter' now is deprecated. So replace it with the following:

`<AnimatePresence mode="sync"> ... </AnimatePresence>`