# In Framer Motion how to remove bounce on AnimatePresence?

Tags: carousel, framer-motion, chakra-ui

Playing with Framer Motion after building my motion I've noticed that when cycling through `AnimatePresence` there is a bounce off the `div`.

variants:

```
const variants = {
  enter: ({ direction, width }) => ({ x: direction * width }),
  center: { x: 0 },
  exit: ({ direction, width }) => ({ x: direction * -width })
};
```

AnimatePresence:

```
<Flex flex="1" align="center" justify="center">
  <AnimatePresence
    mode="wait"
    initial={false}
    custom={{ direction, width }}
  >
    <motion.div
      key={index}
      variants={variants}
      initial="enter"
      animate="center"
      exit="exit"
      custom={{ direction, width }}
      w="full"
    >
      // removed code
    </motion.div>
  </AnimatePresence>
</Flex>
```

Referencing the docs and under [`Exit animations`](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/##exit-animations) has the same behavior and was used as a reference when building mine. Didin't see anything under [`props`](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/#props) to show how to stop the bounce.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-image-gallery-pqvx3?from-embed)

Looked under a few existing questions:

- [odd behavior with framer motion animate on presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079635/odd-behavior-with-framer-motion-animate-on-presence)
- [Framer-Motion AnimatePresence Choppy Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72499170/framer-motion-animatepresence-choppy-animation)
- [framer-motion AnimatePresence layout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61393269/framer-motion-animatepresence-layout-issue)
- [Framer Motion AnimatePresence Nested Import Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66903599/framer-motion-animatepresence-nested-import-problem)
- [Can't get AnimatePresence in Framer Motion to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695907/cant-get-animatepresence-in-framer-motion-to-work)
- [React js framer motion AnimatePresence not work on Exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73556327/react-js-framer-motion-animatepresence-not-work-on-exit)

In Framer Motion is there a way to remove the bounce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the transition with the [`transition`](https://www.framer.com/motion/transition/) prop on motion elements. The `transition` prop allows you to do all sorts of animations, including removing the bounce from the spring animation. In your code, you are using [value-specific transitions](https://www.framer.com/motion/transition/##value-specific-transitions), which allows you to set transition for a specific value. The `x` transition is set to "spring". To remove the bounce from your animation, update your transition like so:

```
transition={{
    x: { type: "spring", bounce: 0 },
    opacity: { duration: 0.2 }
}}
```

I often use this [framer motion visualizer](https://framer-motion-visualizer.vercel.app/) to get the spring animation I want. You can also use an [easing function](https://www.framer.com/motion/transition/###ease) for the transition.

Comment: plus one for the visualizer link that was cool

Comment: I was blown away when I found that, it's been super helpful